# error: failed to attach to process ID 1869

Tags: ios, xcode4.3

I'm getting the above error.

I'm running Version 4.3.2 (4E2002) and testing in iPhone 5.0 simulator. 
The simulator opens but i just get black screen the apps not run .
Even I tried:-

1.you can delete the App directy under `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.0/Applications and ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`

2.then you can start Xcode ; in the menubar you can find Project -> Clean
But its not working.

Do i need to  install Xcode again?

Comment: Close both Xcode and simulator before removing the app from applications and cached data from derivedData. Then open project -> clean and run. BTW why are you using such an old version of Xcode?

Comment: Thanks ACB! trying this solution now...old version of Xcode :as i am using Macbook OS X version 10.7.4 with 2GB, My system already becomes slow.

Comment: No! Now i am installing another simulator !

Comment: Try restarting your mac then. Ideally restarting your simulator should work in these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all,

After spending 2 hour and reading a lot of option this solution work for me.

I install another simulator and run my app( it again show me black screen only).

[image]

Reset content and setting for both simulators.

[image]

Clean the project.

Removing the app from applications and cached data from derivedData.(Thanks ACB)

Restart Mac.

Open Project and change Debugger to GDB

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Kill the iphone simulator and try again

Comment: i already try it even i reset content and settings of my simulator.

Comment: you have to close /terminate the iphone simulator